# Broken supsend screen AMD apu

Tags: suspend

I searched a lot for that problem but I still  do not know what should to do
since I'm new to linux - ubuntu.
My problem is when I make my laptop suspend or sleep and then when I come back to open it laptop give me broken log in screen and the only way to run my laptop again it press the power button for 15 s till shutdown then start it and it work normal with no problem.
If I make it sleep or suspend the fan does  not have sound and the light of power button starts to flash (( as if I make my laptop sleep in windows)) and sometime I can see the Cursor and I can move it.

[image: login screen]

My laptop:

hp elitebook 745 g3
amd apu a10-pro8700B

gpu driver:

[image: my gpu driver]

gpu R6 
 4gb ram 
 120gb ssd 
 os > ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Why are you showning NVIDA driver? I have this same laptop and driver should be AMD R5R6R7